# Find and replace text with slash characters

Tags: regex, string, perl, replace, slash

So I looked around on Stackoverflow and I understand finding and replacing text works something like this:

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/www.example.com/www.pressbin.com/g;' *.html
```

However, what if the text I want to find and replace is a filepath that has slashes? How do I do it then?

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/path/to/file/new/path/to/file/g;' *.html
```

Comment: What does this have to do with ssh ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With perl regexes, you can use *any* character except spaces as regex delimiter, although

- Characters in `\w` (so `s xfooxbarx` is the same as `s/foo/bar/`) and
- Question marks  `?` (implicitly activates match-only-once behaviour, deprecated) and
- single quotes `'...'` (turns of variable interpolation)

should be avoided. I prefer curly braces:

```
perl -pi -w -e 's{path/to/file}{new/path/to/file}g;' *.html
```

The delimiting character may not occur inside the respective strings, except when they are balanced braces or properly escaped. So you *could* also say

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/path\/to\/file/new\/path\/to\/file/g;' *.html
```

but that is dowrnright ugly.

When using braces/parens etc there can be whitespace between the regex and the replacement, allowing for beatiful code like

```
$string =~ s {foo}
             {bar}g;
```

Another interesting regex option in this context is the `quotemeta` function. If your search expression contains many characters that would usually be interpreted with a special meaning, we can enclose that string inside `\Q...\E`. So

```
m{\Qx*+\E}
```

matches the exact string `x*+`, even if characters like `*`, '+' or `|` etc. are included.

Answer (score 3):

You can use other characters than '/' to specify patterns. For example:

```
perl -pi -w -e 's,path/to/file,new/path/to/file,g;' *.html
```

Answer (score 0):

`perl -pi -w -e 's/path\/to\/file/new\/path\/to\/file/g;' *.html`