# replace a string containing forward slash "/" in perl

Tags: perl

I am string to replace a string containing "/" using Perl, using below code

file.txt contains

```
/usr/open/xyz -getCh $svr
```

code

```
open(FILE, "</tmp/file.txt") || die "File not found";
my @lines = <FILE>;
close(FILE);
 my $stringToReplace = "\/usr\/open\/xyz -getCh \$svr";
 my $stringToReplaceWith = "echo \"y\" | \/usr\/open\/xyz -getCh \$svr";
my @newlines;
foreach(@lines) {
   $_ =~ s/$stringToReplace/$stringToReplaceWith/g;
   push(@newlines,$_);
}

open(FILE, ">/tmp/file.txt") || die "File not found";
print FILE @newlines;
close(FILE);
```

The above code is not working for me.

Comment: Dude. You can use any character to mark the borders of the regexp. As you don't give any information regarding how it "does not work", I'll assume you have problems because you use "/" to mark the regexp.
use this line instead for example:
$_ =~ s{$stringToReplace}{$stringToReplaceWith}g;

Comment: This has nothing to do with slashes. The problem is (probably) that `$` in a regex looks for end-of-string, not a literal dollar sign. But "the code is not working" is not a problem description, and you don't seem to have spent any effort on tracking down the problem yourself (your code is far from minimal).

Comment: Start every Perl file with `use strict; use warnings;`.

Comment: Use lexical variables, not bareword filehandles.

Comment: Use 3-arg open, not 2-arg open.

Comment: `File not found` is not a helpful error message, especially if that wasn't the actual problem. Include the name of the file you're trying to open in the error message, as well as `$!` (which contains the real reason the open failed).

Comment: You don't have to escape `/` in a double-quoted string. `"\/usr\/open\/xyz"` is the same as `"/usr/open/xyz"`.

Comment: Why are you creating a separate array (`@newlines`) when you're modifying `@lines` in place? At the end of your program `@lines` and `@newlines` have identical contents.

Comment: I have tried using another variable as the delimiter but it seems that it is not able to search the string, I am not getting any error but the string is not getting replaced it seems that it is not able to search the string.I have tried even without escape characters but it is not able to search the string.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616395/perl-regular-expression-using-variable-as-search-string-with-perl-operator-char

Comment: The \Q option is working for me ..Thanks Chris

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and replace text with slash characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238384/find-and-replace-text-with-slash-characters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some notes on your code

- *Always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every Perl program you write
- Use lexical file handles and the three-parameter form of `open`
- An `open` call may fail for many reasons other than that the file cannot be found. The error message is in `$!`  and you should include it in your `die` string
- Using single quotes removes the need for most backslashes in string literals. Forward slashes don't need to be escaped inside eithern single or double quotes
- You should `use constant` to define constant values, especially if you use more than once
- Use the fact that many of Perl's operators default to acting on `$_`
- There is no need for the array `@newlines`. You are modifying `@lines` anyway so `@newlines` is just a copy
- Use `\Q...\E` in regex patterns or double-quoted strings to escape every non-alphanumeric character

The last point will solve your problem. A dollar sign `$` inside a regex pattern means the end 0f a line, and needs to be escaped if you want it taken literally

This variation of your program works correctly

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use constant FILE => '/tmp/file.txt';

my @input = do {
    open my $fh, '<', FILE or die "Unable to open input file: $!";
    <$fh>;
};

my $old = '/usr/open/xyz -getCh $svr';
my $new = 'echo "y" | ' . $old;

open my $fh, '>', FILE or die "Unable to open output file: $!";

for ( @input ) {
    s/\Q$old/$new/g;
    print $fh $_;
}

print "Changes complete\n";
```